# Datepicker Support in IE11 and Firefox

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, datepicker, internet-explorer-11

What is wrong with this simple HTML page that a date picker is not shown in FireFox 30.0 and IE 11?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label> Date field:</label><br />
            <input type="date" value="" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @dreamcrash Yes, I am unemployed.

Comment: @dreamcrash You may write me. See my profile.

Comment: Okey, my friend have wrote you an email so that you guys can get into contact

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 does not currently support `<input type='date'>`, though we did [recently announce](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/12/08/status-roadmap-update-srcset-lt-main-gt-element-and-date-inputs-in-development.aspx) that work was underway to do so. You can track that progress online at [http://status.modern.ie](https://status.modern.ie/daterelatedinputtypes?term=date).

Firefox [supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) `<input type='date'>`. The bug requesting support was closed on [June 22, 2016](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=825294)

If you need this functionality *today*, I would encourage you to use [jQuery's Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: is this fixed now  its not working in IE 11 & I don't see it working even in ( emulated ) Edge browser

Comment: This work was completed and shipped in build 10240 of Windows 10. Which version of Edge are you presently testing?

Comment: Thanks for reply ..I am using the emulator that comes with IE 11 ..  will it have these updates or can i update that emulator externally ..

Comment: @user666 Internet Explorer 11 doesn't ship with an Edge emulator. I believe you're confusing the Microsoft Edge browser with the Document Mode Edge available in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I pressed F12 and on far left side there is option to select browser Edge to IE 5 are coming there. Are you saying that it is not the Emulator .If not what is the purpose of it. In document mode as well Edge is coming. For my knowledge can you tell me what is the purpose of it. thanks.

Comment: @user666 No, this is not an emulator. This option causes a functional regression in Internet Explorer's engine, cause it to behave more like earlier versions of itself. You can *largely* "emulate" older versions of Internet Explorer, but you **cannot** emulate a newer version, or a newer browser, like Microsoft Edge. "Edge" in the IE tools refers to the unmodified, most recent behavior, of the engine in *that particular version of Internet Explorer*. It's a description, rather than a name.

Comment: That status.modern.ie link seems to be dead by now.

Comment: If you can't get the jQuery UI datepicker to work with Bootstrap 4, make sure you're using the FULL version of jQuery, not the SLIM (the Bootstrap 4 sample docs use the SLIM which is fine if you don't need a datepicker).

Comment: FYI to all commenters/readers - Internet Explorer hasn't been receiving feature updates for some time now. If something is not yet added to IE by now, it never will be. Microsoft has moved on to supporting Edge, the replacement browser for IE.

Answer (score 9):

#### Feb 2019 Update:

Edge supports the datepicker, but after 4+ years, it looks like IE never will.  Same with Safari desktop (though Safari mobile supports it).  See: [CanIUse datepicker support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime).

Chrome and Edge take the date format from the user's desktop system settings, which may be surprising if you're expecting [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and your users don't live in Denmark or Canada.

JQuery's datepicker works with bootstrap 4 only if you use the REGULAR JQuery distribution.  the Bootstrap 4 docs show the SLIM version, which tripped me up for a bit.

Other alternatives:

- [uxsolutions bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) "A datepicker for Bootstrap forked from Stefan Petre's (of eyecon.ro), improvements by eternicode" has a lot of stars on github and seems to work with bootstrap 4.
- Some friends recommended the [eyecon Datepicker for Bootstrap](https://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) which I guess is the original that uxsolutions is forked from.
- [Pickaday](https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday) is pretty popular, though the [JS Deliver CDN](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/) currently lacks an integrity hashcode and there's no pre-built download - you have to build with node or something.

Answer (score 0):

It is already in Firefox since version 51 (January 26, 2017), but it is not activated by default (yet). To activate it:

Go to "about:config" in your address bar, then search for the `dom.forms.datetime` property and set it to `true`.