# HTML How to make the datepicker visible on Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: css, html, forms, internet-explorer

The tag  is shown as of type text on Internet Explorer 11 while it is showing properly on Chrome. The calendar pop-up is not being shown.

Chrome did not experience such issue.

```
    <div id="user_data">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>
                <label>Enter File Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="dirname" value="Enter File Name here">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Expiry Date:</label>
                <input type="date" name="expDate">
            <p>

            <p>
                <input class ="f" type="file" name="file">
            </p>

            <p>
                <input id="doneBtn" type="submit" value="Upload">
            </p>
        </form> 

    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534118/datepicker-support-in-ie11-and-firefox

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to make <input type=“date”> supported on all browsers? Any alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020950/how-to-make-input-type-date-supported-on-all-browsers-any-alternatives) or [How to get HTML 5 input type=“date” working in Firefox and/or IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These form fields were never implemented in Internet Explorer and therefore degrade to a default text field. See for support details: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

You would need to use a javascript polyfill/replacement to display a datepicker in IE11. e.g. https://github.com/brianblakely/nodep-date-input-polyfill